# API of Polarion ALM occasionally does not authorize any request

Tags: api, web-services, soap

I have wrote some Python code that logs in and reads some data from Polarion ALM server via API (more informarion about Polarion API: https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/index.html). In my code I have used zeep Python package to handle SOAP.

My algorithm is simple:
1) Log in via logIn web service (https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/ws/client/session/SessionWebService.html#logIn-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-)
2) Add current session to header - so the current session remain alive.
3) Try to read some data, for example via getRootProjectGroup web service (https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/ws/client/projects/ProjectWebService.html#getRootProjectGroup--).
4) Regardless of what is happening I close the current session via endSession web service (https://almdemo.polarion.com/polarion/sdk/doc/javadoc/com/polarion/alm/ws/client/session/SessionWebService.html#endSession--).

What I observed:
Ocassionally, at point 3 I receive response with Authorization Error (snippet with response):
`<soapenv:Fault>\n      <faultcode>soapenv:Server.generalException</faultcode>\n      <faultstring>Not authorized.</faultstring>\n      <detail>\n        <ns1:stackTrace xmlns:ns1="http://xml.apache.org/axis/">Not authorized.\n\tat com.polarion.alm.ws.providers.DoAsUserWrapper.invoke(DoAsUserWrapper.java:37)\n\tat org.apache.axis.strategies.InvocationStrategy.visit(InvocationStrategy.java:32)\n\t..`
or everything is good and I receive:

```
{
    'groupURIs': {
        'SubterraURI': [
            'subterra:data-service:objects:/default/${ProjectGroup}Group'
        ]
    },
    'location': None,
    'name': 'ROOT_CTX_NAME',
    'parentURI': None,
    'projectIDs': None,
    'uri': 'subterra:data-service:objects:${ProjectGroup}Group',
    'unresolvable': False
}
```

What surprises me the most:
- I always uses the same credential (username and password)
- the session ID of the in request (point 3) is the same as in the server response during log in (point 1) so the session shall remain alive
- if I put my code in the loop (for example 1000 executions), the result for all attempts is always the same (1000 successes or 1000 failures), even if I add a wait (e.g. 1s) between the attemps

I would like to know why server rejects some of the requests. Is it some kind of Polarion server issue? How could I make a work around to somehow connect with the server and be able to read some data from the server even if it reject my first request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that it is issue with SOAP client (and relatively popular one). To fix it, I have turned off TLS verification. More details in:
https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io/en/master/transport.html